# Retrieving information from another list based on the ID value that is retrieved from the first list using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am retrieving list information using angular js, now while the information is getting looped, for each list item ID, I need to retrieve information from another list where ID is look up column from the first list.

I tried the following code, but am unable to retrieve data from the second list

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({

            method: 'GET',

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items?$select=ID,Created,Description,Title,Favourites,Author/Title&$expand=Author/Title",

            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                data.d.results.forEach(function(customer) {

                var id=customer["ID"];
                customer["Description"] = customer["Description"].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
         $http({

            method: 'GET',

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Answers')/items?$select=QuestionID&$filter=QuestionID eq "+id+"",

            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {


            $scope.answers = data.d.results;



        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {



        });


        });
            $scope.customers = data.d.results;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        }); 
});
```

Comment: You can use `$expand` operator as the Item Id is looked up with another list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup column information can be retrieved using `$expand` operator. For example:

List **A** has column `Title`, `Name` and List **B** has column `Title`, `Name` and Lookup column named `LookupA` (Lookup list is **A**). So if you are querying in **B** list, then your query should look like

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items?$select=Title,Name,LookupA/Title,LookupA/Name&$expand=LookupA
```

`LookupA` will be returned as `object`

Find more about `$expand` [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Use [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to test/explore REST API.

Comment: can you help me with the below question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195092/retrieving-information-from-two-lists